# Redirect user with IF condition

Tags: php

I'm like to use this IF to redirect user based on permissions. But user is all time redirected to dashboard.

Actually i have set:

```
$perm_edit = '0';
$user_level = '1';

if ($perm_edit !== 1 || $user_level !== 1) {
      header("Location: $url/dash.php?error=1"); exit;
 }
```

|| operator require only one condition to go ahead.

What do I wrong?

Comment: youre using exactly equals(===) instead of (==)

Comment: *(!==) instead of (!=)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The triple comparison operators are "strict", meaning they check type as well as value. You are comparing strings to numbers, which means they will always be false. Either turn them both into numbers, or just use double comparisons: `$perm_edit != 1`

Comment: Or `+$perm_edit === 1 || +$user_level === 1` should work too.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté That would work, but why do the type conversion manually and *then* do a strict comparison, when PHP will do the type conversion automatically if you use a normal comparison? There is no benefit here in using a strict comparison.

Comment: @Atli Because I like to overcomplicate things. `=]`

Comment: @user2307958 If the problem is still not fixed, then the logic must be faulty. With that IF statement, if either `$perm_edit` or `$user_level` are NOT `1`, then it redirects. Is that really what you were after? More likely you were trying to check if both weren't 1, in which case you are looking for the *and* (`&&`) operator, not *or* (`||`). - If that's not right, explain what is supposed to be happening.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I know what you mean. I have a tendency to do that as well `:)`

Comment: But, what difference between || and && ??

Comment: @user2307958 Their meaning, as I suggested before, is `OR` and `AND`. The difference is exactly that same as the difference in their meaning in normal speech. - I suggest you read the Logical Operators section of the PHP manual thoroughly. (http://goo.gl/s5Fyvd) This is not something you want to be fuzzy about if you plan on continuing to program. That, by the way, is independent of the language you are using; this stuff is pretty much the same in all of them.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using the **not identical to** operator (`!==`). It does not do [type juggling](http://php.net/juggling), which is what you need in this case.

In order to find out if two *values*, of different *types*, are equivalent, you must use the **not equal to** operator (`!=`):

```
if ($perm_edit != 1 || $user_level != 1) {
    header("Location: $url/dash.php?error=1");
    exit;
}
```

Another way to write that is:

```
if ( ! $perm_edit || ! $user_level) {
    header("Location: $url/dash.php?error=1");
    exit;
}
```

The reason that works is because PHP juggles the types. In other words, it turns `0` into `false` and `1` into `true`, and then the `!` operator (also called the NOT operator) turns it into the opposite.

You should read up on [comparison operators](http://php.net/operators.comparison) and [operators](http://php.net/operators) in general.